# What are the techniques to find the sum to infinity of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a series, what are the techniques to find a formula that sums the series to infinity?

I only know the method of multiplying the series with a factor and then taking their difference (like [here](http://youtu.be/AiQuXEsZCyU?t=2m8s)). But today, I found out that we can also try to find such a formula by differentiation (see answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595434/help-find-sum-to-infinity-of-a-series-odd-numbers-with-a-common-ratio) question).

Therefore, I was wondering what other techniques exist and if there is a book/online resource that I can read to understand the logic behind them?

Comment: The biggest problem with something like infinite series is that, even if they're convergent, it's rare that you'll be able to find a closed form.
Some techniques include finding the limit of the sequence of partial sums, comparing with integrals, using techniques from analysis to estimate bounds, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many techniques, but unfortunately there is no general method which is guaranteed to succeed, hence the difficulty (perhaps impossibility) of finding things like a closed formula for $\zeta(3)$.

The techniques that I can recall using in the past include:

- Using known power series expansions (including things like geometric series)
- Differentiating or integrating power series
- Using complex analysis (look for summation of series by using residues) as [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/304681/32441)
- Fourier expansions, including Parseval's theorem - as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71706/32441)

However, there is no method which is always going to work, so it means lots of practice to gain experience!

I am sure others will be able to suggest more modern books, but one I have is:

Konrad Knopp - "[Theory and Application of Infinite Series](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Theory-Application-Infinite-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486661652)" (Dover edition) which has a whole chapter on closed and numerical expressions for sums of series.

Comment: Generations of mathematicians have read that Knopp book.  Unless you speak German, be glad that is had been translated...

Comment: I have used it many times, and still delve into it sometimes - luckily in English :)