# Partial sums over rational functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I recently came across the result that

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^4-n^3+n+1}{n^6-1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

I am wondering how one could proof this, generally how one could evaluate a sum over rational functions.

If I plug the sum into Wolfram Alpha it gives

$$\frac{3k^4-k-2}{6k(k+1)(k^2+k+1)}$$

as the $k$-th partial sum. Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, this would in fact proof the upper equality.

Sadly, I could not wrap my head around how to get to Wolfram Alphas partial sum result. If anyone has an idea let me know. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: You could prove it by induction.

Comment: See [What are the techniques to find the sum to infinity of a series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/595490/318073). There is not always a closed form, see [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apéry%27s_constant).

Comment: In general you cannot expect the partial sums of a rational function to have a closed form. e.g., even $\sum_{n=1}^k 1/n$ is the $k$-th harmonic number which does not to my knowledge have a closed form.  So, in some sense this series is special, although you can generate examples like this by taking the differences $f(n+1) - f(n)$ for a given rational function $f$.

Comment: As for techniques for finding the sum, maybe use partial fractions and hope it telescopes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word: the terms telescope in a nice way.

Using partial fractions, we have
$$
\frac{n^4-n^3+n+1}{n^6-1} = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{n - 2}{n^2 - n + 1}-  \frac{n-1}{n^2 + n + 1}  + \frac{1}{n - 1} - \frac{1}{n + 1}\right)
$$We need to be a bit careful because the harmonic series diverges, so we should only group terms with opposite signs together. The last two terms form a well-known telescoping series:
$$
\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=2}^{m}\left(\frac{1}{n - 1} - \frac{1}{n + 1} \right)= \frac{1}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1}\right)\longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}
$$The first two terms telescope as well, with the second term eating the one before it:
$$
\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=2}^{m}\left(\frac{n - 2}{n^2 - n + 1}-  \frac{n-1}{n^2 + n + 1} \right)= -\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{m-1}{m^2+m+1}\longrightarrow 0
$$This sort of thing won't work in general but I won't look a gift horse in the mouth.